# notepad ++ and regex for double words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have around 6000 strings from Android Studio, which I need to modify.

My translator did a big mistake, and made the translations like this

```
<string name="rej">Отклонено</string> Noraidīts
<string name="com">Выполнено</string> Izpildīts
  <string name="select_img">Выбрать картинку</string> Izvēlēties attēlu
    <string name="select_pic">Выбрать фотографию</string> Izvēlēties fotoattēlu
```

As you can see, translated word is added after `</string>`, so I need manually take word or words after`</string>` and put them between `<string>HERE</string>`

To do it manually is quite hard.

Can you help me with regex in Notepad++?

BTW, I managed to regex if my string is one word and translated string also one word
Example:

```
<string name="rej">Отклонено</string> Noraidīts
```

This was done using:

```
(<string name="\w+">)\w+(</string>) (\w+)
```

But, if my string has double word like

```
<string name="select_img">word1 word2</string> word1 word2
```

I don't know the correct regex,

Can you help me, please?

Comment: at the top you priide 4line example - can you provide 4line result of this example which you wanna to get?

Comment: Find What: `(<string[^>]*>).*?(</string>)\h*(.*)` and replace with `$1$3$2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<string name="\w+">\K.*?(</string>)\h*(.+)`
- Replace with: `$2$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<string name="\w+">     # start tag with variable name
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
.+?                     # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
(</string>)             # group 1, end tag
\h*                     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(.+)                    # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline, the translation
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2, the translation
$1          # content of group 1, end tag
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<string name="rej">Noraidīts</string>
<string name="com">Izpildīts</string>
  <string name="select_img">Izvēlēties attēlu</string>
    <string name="select_pic">Izvēlēties fotoattēlu</string>
```

**Capture screen:**

[image]

Comment: BEST! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it is about word characters, you could repeat a group 0+ times prepended with a space `\w+(?: \w+)*` or match 1+ times a horizontal whitespace character `\h+` instead of a space only:

```
(<string name="\w+">)\w+(?: \w+)*(</string>) (\w+(?: \w+)*)
```

In the replacement you could use `$1$3$2`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h6j5Vc/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can make groups in Regex ().
You can build as many groups as you want to, and then you can get the value of that group by typing $1 for the first group etc.
So if you take this Regex:

```
(<string name="\w+">)(\w+)(</string>) (\w+)
```

You will have 4 groups and then you can replace and reorder the groups as you want.
I guess in your case it will be:

```
$1$3$2$4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that you are only looking for word characters `\w` you also need to add space to your search set. Something like `[\w ]`. I have just assumed there might be special chars also so I have replaced your `\w` with `.`

You can do something like this

find:

```
(<string name=".+">).+(<\/string>) (.+)
```

replace with:

```
\1\3\2
```

demo here:
https://regex101.com/r/roi1Yx/3

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is:

```
<string name="(.+)">(.+)<\/string> (.+)
```

Were:

- group 1 is name
- group 2 is russian word(s)
- group 3 is translated word(s)

You can test it [here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=107958)

Comment: thanks!
But, what if my <string name="test">/час</string> - has SLASH before? and : after , like Сумма:

Comment: It should still matches. You can check it by adding new "Test string" here https://www.regextester.com/?fam=107958

Comment: Strings like this still mathecs correctly:
<string name="test">/час</string> /hour
<string name="test">Сумма:</string> Summ: